# Fetch doesn't returns promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Using fetch in React Native to chain promises gives me next error:

`Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        loaded: false
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.login().then(function(){
        console.log('Success');
    }, function() {
        console.log('Fail')
    })
}

login() {
    return fetch(LOGIN_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers : MOBILE_PLATFORM_HEADERS
    })
    .then((response) =>response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
            loaded : true
        });
    })
    .done();
}
```

I bounded this to login in constructor, also, as stated in fetch Api - Fetch returns promise - I'm returning fetch from login function but result is always the same. What am I missing?

Comment: remove the `.done()` line from the `login` method and then it will work

Comment: You men are my hero :) Answer the question so I could accept it.

Comment: It is ok :) Glad if it works for you!